# display images from database with baguettebox

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to display images from my database with baguetteBox.js The problem is, baguetteBox works with `<a>` tags, but I display the images with  `<img>` tags. I insert them in mediumblob to my database, and I don't have them in any folders.
So, here's the working baguetteBox:

```
<div class="card-buttons">
<a href="1.jpg">
<div class="kepek">
<div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Képek</button>
</div>
</a>
<a href="2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

and here's the working image listing:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM cardimages ORDER BY id DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" /><br/>
<?php       
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

but with this one, I can't see any image:

```
<div class="card-buttons">
<a href="1.jpg">
<div class="kepek">
<div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Képek</button>
</div>
</a>
<a href="2.jpg"></a>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM cardimages ORDER BY id DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<a href="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"></a>

<?php       
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Element `<a>` is a link, you must add content to the link. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: I know how it works. My problem is, that my images wont show up with 'a' tag but that's the only thing baguetteBox accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `<img>` tag inside the `<a>` element that baguetteBox needs in order to trigger the lightbox. A link element will never display an image [See the second example on their homepage](https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/)

So replace this line in your php file:

```
<a href="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"></a>
```

with something like this (I'm assuming.. you might need to edit it some)

```
<a href="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
    <img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />
</a>
```

Comment: The images display next to my button, but can't see them in the gallery with this. :/

Comment: @kristof12301 not really sure what you mean given this code. Do you have a link to page your workign on?

Comment: sorry too many issues to solve here :( need to restructure your html I think. If you want images inside button try something like this ```<div class="button"><a href="img.png"><img src="img.png"/></a></div>```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed those issues. Now you can see the exact problem. There is one image that comes from my database, but with your code it displays outside of the button, right on the index page, but you can't see it if you click on the 'képek' button.